# Question YOLOv2 bounding box prior

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, yolo

In the [YOLO9000 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08242.pdf), they define the distance between a box and centroid as $d(box, centroid) = 1 - IOU(box, centroid)$. I think box here is a ground truth bounding box, but what is centroid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The centroid is referring to the central point of a [k-means cluster](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/06/centroid-initialization-k-means-clustering.html).

Where does k-means come in? At the end of p.2 they say:

> Instead of choosing priors by hand, we run k-means clustering on the training set bounding boxes to automatically find good priors.

Also see Figure 2.